# How to save a Seaborn plot into a file

Tags: python, pandas, file, output, seaborn

I tried the following code (`test_seaborn.py`):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
sns_plot = sns.pairplot(df, hue='species', size=2.5)
fig = sns_plot.get_figure()
fig.savefig("output.png")
#sns.plt.show()
```

But I get this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_searborn.py", line 11, in <module>
    fig = sns_plot.get_figure()
AttributeError: 'PairGrid' object has no attribute 'get_figure'
```

I expect the final `output.png` will exist and look like this:

[image]

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: [@Terry Wang's answer down below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47765118/7954106) worked for me - `Python 2.7.12` and `seaborn 0.7.1`

Comment: A one-liner for `seaborn 0.9`: `sns.regplot(x='age', y='income', data=pd.read_csv('income_data.csv')).get_figure().savefig('income_f_age.png')`

Answer (score 400):

The following calls allow you to access the figure (Seaborn 0.8.1 compatible):

```
swarm_plot = sns.swarmplot(...)
fig = swarm_plot.get_figure()
fig.savefig("out.png")
```

as seen previously in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35670528/1079075).

The suggested solutions are incompatible with Seaborn 0.8.1. They give the following errors because the Seaborn interface has changed:

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'fig'
When trying to access the figure

AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'savefig'
when trying to use the savefig directly as a function
```

---

**UPDATE:**
I have recently used `PairGrid` object from seaborn to generate a plot similar to the one in [this example](http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/pairgrid_dotplot.html).
In this case, since `GridPlot` is not a plot object like, for example, `sns.swarmplot`, it has no `get_figure()` function.
It is possible to directly access the matplotlib figure by:

```
fig = myGridPlotObject.fig
```

Comment: I have recently used PairGrid object from seaborn as in the example

Comment: This is the only answer that works for PairGrid and JointGrid as well, I think it should be accepted.

Comment: The requirement of get_figure to save the figure is very annoying. It should be possible using on line to save a plot to a file.

Answer (score 85):

Some of the above solutions did not work for me. The `.fig` attribute was not found when I tried that and I was unable to use `.savefig()` directly. However, what did work was:

```
sns_plot.figure.savefig("output.png")
```

I am a newer Python user, so I do not know if this is due to an update. I wanted to mention it in case anybody else runs into the same issues as I did.

Comment: This worked for me with a `seaborn.swarmplot`, but for `seaborn.lmplot` that won't work. With `seaborn.lmplot`, I found `sns_plot.savefig("output.png")` worked like in Salvatore's answer, but without need for `get_figure()` call.

Comment: This worked for `displot` with seaborn `0.11.2`. The only answer I could get to work!

Answer (score 35):

Fewer lines for 2019 searchers:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
sns_plot = sns.pairplot(df, hue='species', height=2.5)
plt.savefig('output.png')
```

UPDATE NOTE: `size` was changed to `height`.

Comment: it produces white image!

Comment: @user_007 not sure why you're getting white image. I just tested the code today and it's fine to both Jupyter Notebook and the output file. You might want to update your console/Python and check your computer View settings.

Comment: I had a white figure as well. I corrected it with:
`sns_plot.savefig('output.png')`

Comment: Works for pdf output too.

Answer (score 17):

You should just be able to use the `savefig` method of `sns_plot` directly.

```
sns_plot.savefig("output.png")
```

For clarity with your code if you did want to access the matplotlib figure that `sns_plot` resides in then you can get it directly with

```
fig = sns_plot.fig
```

In this case there is no `get_figure` method as your code assumes.

Answer (score 12):

I use `distplot` and `get_figure` to save picture successfully.

```
sns_hist = sns.distplot(df_train['SalePrice'])
fig = sns_hist.get_figure()
fig.savefig('hist.png')
```

Comment: Worked for my environment: function `sns.distplot()` in  `python 3.5.6` with `seaborn 0.9.0` .           Besides, function `sns.pairplot()` doesn't need the line of `get_figure()`

Answer (score 12):

I couldnt get the other answers to work and finally got this to work for me for matplotlib==3.2.1 . Its especially true if you are doing this within a for loop or some iterative approach.

```
sns.scatterplot(
    data=df_hourly, x="date_week", y="value",hue='variable'
)
plt.savefig('./f1.png')
plt.show()
```

Note that the savefig must be before the show call. Otherwise an empty image is saved.

Comment: This actually helped! Thank you. This is the only way it worked for me in Jupyter Notebook

Comment: @Anscandance good to hear ! Yeah, i couldnt get the other solutions to work properly as well in the notebook.

Comment: Can confirm this works with Matplotlib version 3.7.1 as well. All of the other answers in this thread did not work.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

sns.factorplot(x='holiday',data=data,kind='count',size=5,aspect=1)
plt.savefig('holiday-vs-count.png')
```

Answer (score 4):

Its also possible to just create a matplotlib `figure` object and then use `plt.savefig(...)`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
plt.figure() # Push new figure on stack
sns_plot = sns.pairplot(df, hue='species', size=2.5)
plt.savefig('output.png') # Save that figure
```

Comment: Doesn't work at least with `displot`

Answer (score 2):

You would get an error for using `sns.figure.savefig("output.png")` in seaborn 0.8.1.

Instead use:

```
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
sns_plot = sns.pairplot(df, hue='species', size=2.5)
sns_plot.savefig("output.png")
```

Answer (score -4):

Just FYI, the below command worked in seaborn 0.8.1 so I guess the initial answer is still valid.

```
sns_plot = sns.pairplot(data, hue='species', size=3)
sns_plot.savefig("output.png")
```

Comment: Although that code is working, it is not complete. The title says, 'How to save a Seaborn plot into a file' which is more general.
Unluckily the proposed solution works with pairplot, but it raises an exception with other 'kinds' of plots. Hopefully in future releases there will a more unified way to obtain the 'figure' object from a seaborn plot.