# How to save a plot in Seaborn with Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a Pandas dataframe and try to save a plot in a png file. However, it seems that something doesn't work as it should. This is my code:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style='ticks')

df = pandas.read_csv("this_is_my_csv_file.csv")
plot = sns.distplot(df[['my_column_to_plot']])
plot.savefig("myfig.png")
```

And I have this error:

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'savefig'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `plt.savefig` because your picture will come up when you'll call `plt.show()`

Comment: @Tasos it can be that they made a Figure object, with `fig = plt.Figure()`. Then you can save the figure with `fig.savefig()`

Answer (score 23):

You could save any seaborn figure like this.

Suppose If you want to create a violin plot to show the salary distribution gender wise. You could do it like this and will save it using the get_figure method.

```
ax = sns.violinplot(x="Gender", y="Salary", hue="Degree", data=job_data)
#Returns the :class:~matplotlib.figure.Figure instance the artist belongs to
fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.savefig('gender_salary.png')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `plt.savefig('yourTitle.png')`

If you want to pass a variable:

```
plt.savefig("yourTitleDataSet{0}.png".format(dataset))
```