# Seaborn pairplot legend - how to control position

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to move the Seaborn pairplot legend outside the scatter plot matrix. The official [docs](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) don't give a keyword `legend`. I am trying to plot the legend outside the plot in 3 different locations simultaneously: bottom center, top center, right center

I have tried this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.pairplot(iris,hue='species', palette='husl', markers='d', size=2.5, plot_kws=
    {
    "s":40,
    "alpha":1.0,
    'lw':0.5,
    'edgecolor':'k'
    })
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(1.10, 1.0), ncol=1) #vertical legend
plt.legend(loc='lower center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.0, -0.15), ncol=3) #horizontal legend bottom
plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.0, 1.15), ncol=3) #horizontal legend top
g.savefig('Test.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

The output of the above code is this file: [image: output file].

All 3 legends are being printed incorrectly. I am not sure if it is doing the positioning that I requested. I am not sure what is happening on the right - it seems that 2 vertical legends are appearing and for some reason and they are fully overlapping each other. One of the two horizontal legends is not appearing at all.

Is there a way to avoid overlapping the vertical legends and also place the legend outside the plot in 3 locations - top center, bottom center, right center?

Comment: The default location is vertically oriented on the right outside as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244753/how-to-save-a-seaborn-plot-into-a-file). But, there must be a way to plot the legend in one of these 3 locations. Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`pairplot` already adds a legend outside the plot matrix and it is not clear where you want to move it. The other legends are probably being positioned as you requested even if that might be not what you actually want.

`plt.legend` will attach a legend to the current axes and there can be only one legend per axes so in your code only the last legend is drawn. But you can attach several legends to a figure and IIUC you want to position the legends relative to the figure so figure legends seems like the best option.

In order to plot figure legends you need to explicitly pass the handlers and labels. I had to use the private attribute `PairPlot._legend_data` for that, I did not find a way to do it using the public API.

Unfortunately matplotlib won't automatically make room to acomodate these legends and they will overlap with the subplots unless you make some adjustments. I will just use `subplot_adjust` with some hardcoded values that work for me in this case because calculations are tricky.

So this is the code that hopefully does what you want:

```
g = sns.pairplot(iris, hue='species', palette='husl', markers='d', size=2.5, plot_kws=
    {
    "s":40,
    "alpha":1.0,
    'lw':0.5,
    'edgecolor':'k'
    })

handles = g._legend_data.values()
labels = g._legend_data.keys()
g.fig.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels, loc='upper center', ncol=1)
g.fig.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels, loc='lower center', ncol=3)
g.fig.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels, loc='upper left', ncol=3)
g.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.92, bottom=0.08)
```

[image: pairplot]

The OP asked in a comment whether this can be found in the seaborn documentation. Of course part of this is just pure matplotlib, not specific to seaborn. But I also realized that I had to rely on a couple of undocumented features.

The fact that `PairGrid` has a `fig` attribute referencing the `Figure` instance is not documented. Anyway that was an easy guess and I could have used `fig = plt.gcf()` instead.

Getting the labels and handles of the legend is trickier. I learnt about the `_legend_data` attribute by looking at the docstring of `PairGrid.add_legend`, but the docstring itself is a bit hidden (it does not appear in the web) and the attribute is underscored as if it were private, so using it feels uncomfortable. I find it inconsistent that a private attribute is mentioned in the docstring of a public method, probably we should have `legend_data` as a public attribute, but I digress.

Alternatively you could try to extract the labels and handles from the subplots. You could guess that the subplots have this information but there are no actual guaranties so this means relying on undocumented behaviour. It turns out that the non-diagonal subplots have it (but the diagonal ones don't, so if you just looked at the first subplot you would be misguided) and you can do `handles, labels = fig.get_axes()[1].get_legend_handles_labels()`. But as I said this is undocumented behaviour even if you are using only documented API.

You could also create your own handles but it would be cumbersome, that's why I looked for shortcuts, even if undocumented.

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer to the question. Did you find this in the seaborn documentation?

Comment: @WR I edited the answer, let me know if I didn't address your concerns.

Comment: Done. Great post! No further questions from me on this question. Thanks much, @Goyo!

Comment: One side effect if this approach is that the text `species` is lost from the new legend locations.

Comment: @WR `g.fig.legend(title='species', handles=handles, labels=labels, loc='upper center', ncol=1)`

Comment: Got it! That's really great! Thanks for the update @Goyo.

Comment: Unfortunately, pairplot adds the legend somewhat in the middle of the plot, making it necessary to fiddle around with the location an bbox.

Answer (score 19):

To control the position of the default pairplot legend:

```
    g._legend.set_bbox_to_anchor((0.5, 0.5))
```

Comment: This is the most useful response, IMO

Comment: As a supplement, the (0,0) is the left-bottom corner and the (1,1) is the right-top corner, just like a normal coordinate system. So the default should be (1, 0.5).

Comment: Want to note that at least in Seaborn 0.11.1 ```g.legend``` can be used to access the legend object if you don't want to feel like you're accessing a private attribute.

Answer (score 4):

this helped me, it removes the default legend and there are a lot of settings here.

```
g = sns.pairplot(data, hue="Group")

sns.move_legend(g, "lower center",bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.035), labels=labels, ncol=5, title='Group', frameon=False,)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a lot easier than you'd think it is. It's simply a default setting in the actual matplot output. Just go to the configure subplot button at the top of your output window, and lower your right border upper limit a little and it'll be fixed.

[image: Example with button to click circled]

Comment: Oh I see so you create a Python figure first, then set the legend position and then save it to an image. So you're saying that there is no way to set it programmatically?

Comment: Yeah not I've been able to find. The problem is matplot doesn't recognize it as a table. I suppose you could dig into the pairplot script and see about tinkering with it there, but I don't think it's editable in the way you (and I) tried doing it originally. I saw this same issue on GitHub and no one figured it out there either.