# Getting the numpy array describing an arbitrary matplolib/seaborn plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

Is it possible to get the `numpy` array describing an arbitrary `matplolib`/`seaborn` plot **without** explicitly saving it as an image file and reading it?

For example, say I have the attached image which is a `sns.kdeplot()` of an array. Now, can I get the `numpy` array of this plot without first [saving it to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244753/how-to-save-a-seaborn-plot-into-a-file/39482402#39482402) and reading it? Something like:

```py
img = sns.kdeplot(arr)
img_arr = img.some_function() # Returns a numpy array describing the plot
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`fig.canvas.tostring_rgb()` would be helpful:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.kdeplot(arr, ax=ax)

img_arr = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), 
                        dtype=np.uint8,
                        sep='')
```